# a method to calculate a specific combinatorics problem in java

Tags: combinatorics

there is a factory that produces strings with the letter g u a and r. the probability for each letter that the factory produces is:

- g: 0.3
- u: 0.25
- a: 0.2
- r: 0.25

I need to calculate the approximate amount of times we will get the sequence "g-u-u-a" in a given string length n (n is the parameter that the method gets as an input from user). for example- the method should  calculate the approximate amount of times we will se this sequence in a string with the length of 100 letters (the string is produced by this "factory", which means it has only the letters g, u, a, r).
can someone explain the combinatorics calculation behind it? I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

I tried to calculate the probability of this sequence * the string length, but I have a gut feeling that it is not accurate

Thanks,
Saar

Comment: This is a simple math problem, not a "code" problem.

Comment: Easiest is to compute the expected number of occurrences.  For that, you can use Linearity of Expectation.  More detail is harder to come by.

Comment: @Bohemian could you please explain then?

Comment: "*I tried to calculate the probability of this sequence $*$ the string length, but I have a gut feeling that it is not accurate*"  That is precisely what you should do, though you have to be a bit more careful about "string length" here.  It will indeed be $\Pr(g)\cdot\Pr(u)\cdot\Pr(u)\cdot\Pr(r)\cdot(\text{# of opportunities})$ but note that you don't have enough space to finish the sequence close enough to the end like if you started from the 99th letter.  It will be $0.3\cdot 0.25^3\cdot (100 - 3)$.  The justification is, as lulu alludes, "linearity of expectation."

Comment: As for the question's relationship to java or other programming languages, I agree that this is a quintessential intro to probability question and should only ever be solved with pen-and-paper approaches and not by coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $97$ possible substrings of length $4$, since the initial index can be anywhere between $0$ and $96$. For each of these substrings, the probability the substring equals `GUUA` is equal to $0.3\cdot 0.25\cdot 0.25\cdot 0.2$. Therefore, the expected number of substrings equal to `GUUA` is equal to
$$
97\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.25^2\cdot 0.2=0.36375
$$
Therefore, more than $63.626\%$ of the time, you would expect there to be zero occurrences of `GUUA`.

The number of occurrences should be well approximated by a Poisson random variable. Using this approximation, we get

| Number of occurrences of `GUUA` | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | $\dots$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Approximate probability (using Poisson) | $0.695$ | $0.253$ | $0.046$ | $0.006$ | $\dots$ |